# How to create custome pdf file of my invioice in wordpress

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am creating custom order form in WordPress. now I want to create invoice and download invoice in pdf format how can I do that. I am using dompdf but it shows this error 
**Warning: require_once(dompdf/autoload.inc.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/designcrocs/public_html/wp-content/themes/bridge/pdf.php on line 3**

how can I create a pdf file in WordPress of my order?
Help me...

Comment: What have you attempted? Can you please share what you have done? The error is saying that the file does not exist in your theme folder. Does it exist?

Comment: I cannot find a file. that is a very first problem. I downloaded dompdf folder from that link https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf   and follow youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cON3HJ_zaQM&list=PLxl69kCRkiI23aFg5IG1a8YYRDjvOExIr&index=8   but this video is normal php and I am Applied this is my wordpress website

Comment: Are you using any ECommerce plugin such as WooCommerce?

Comment: How are you creating the order now?

Comment: No, create all thing custom like customer order form admin panel you can check it on https://designcrocs.com

Comment: If you're not using any ECommerce plugin to handle your order and payment, then it's likely you'll need to write some custom code to generate the pdf file, and hook it after people filled in the form.

Comment: yes, I know, but can you give me any source regarding that?

Comment: What's your input thenj? What form are you using? Are you trying to convert HTML to PDF? Or? Please specify what inputs you have now.

Comment: yes, I'm trying HTML To pdf but HTML include some data from database

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're creating this as a [plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) and you've saved the dompdf directory within your plugin directory you can include it with the following.

```
// wp-content/plugins/yourplugin/yourplugin.php
// Set up paths to include DOMPDF
$plugin_path = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ );
define( 'YOURPLUGIN_DOMPDF', $plugin_path . 'dompdf/' );

// Set up directory to save PDF
$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
define( 'YOURPLUGIN_UPLOAD_DIR', $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/invoices');
define( 'YOURPLUGIN_UPLOAD_URL', $upload_dir['baseurl'] . '/invoices');

include( YOURPLUGIN_DOMPDF . 'autoload.inc.php' );
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
use Dompdf\Options;

function yourplugin_order_invoice_pdf(){
  // validate and sanitize your input 
  $options = new Options();
  $options->set('isRemoteEnabled', true);
  $dompdf = new Dompdf($options);

  if ( ! $html = yourplugin_generate_invoice_html( $order_id ) ) {
    return;
  }

  $dompdf->load_html($html);
  $dompdf->render();
  $output = $dompdf->output();
  wp_mkdir_p( YOURPLUGIN_UPLOAD_DIR );
  $file_name = 'order-'.$order_id.'.pdf';
  $file_path = YOURPLUGIN_UPLOAD_DIR . '/'. $file_name;
  file_put_contents( $file_path, $output);
  $invoice_url = YOURPLUGIN_UPLOAD_URL . $file_name;
  return $invoice_url;
}
```

The `yourplugin_order_invoice_pdf` function above is an example of the components needed. You'll probably want to split parts out into their own specific functions, and handle your inputs. Of course you'll need to choose a hook from the [Plugin API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API) to attach this all to.